# How to update resume/LinkedIn after getting promoted from an intern to a steady job?

Tags: resume, internship, promotion, linkedin

I just finished my final year internship at a company **A**, I was offered a job (by the same company) and I accepted it. I'll be continuing to do what I have been doing during my 6 months internship but as an employee.

My question is how do I update my resume/LinkedIn profile to add this new job? I don't want to repeat the same description I have for the internship so I'm looking for a more cleaner way of listing these experiences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can list them as separate but related job experiences (as basically they are the same job, but different contract), modifying some details to better tailor your resume, something like:

> Professional Experience:
>
> 1. Internship at Foo, Inc. as Web Developer [... describe some projects maybe] Jan, 2016 - Jul, 2016.
> 2. Senior Web Developer at Foo, Inc., Aug, 2016 - present.

You can also mention that during any interview you get, as being offered a position after an internship is a good sign that you had a good performance, something interviewers find appealing.

*Note:* As Joe suggests, it seems that the most used way is to sort your work experience from *newest* to *oldest*, so you can reverse the order if you want to follow the standard.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is it ok to add the job with no description? or is it clear from the position title that I'll be doing the same work + some advanced tasks too?

Comment: By placing them one after another, and by indicating that it is the same company and the same position (but no intern now) your interviewer should be able to connect the dots. If you want, you can add description of the job, in a similar way I suggested you describe the internship or another way you consider.

Comment: Yes, it is traditional to sort them from recent to older, good suggestion, should be up to OP to decide how to sort them

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it as a single job, especially since you are doing the same work. Think of it as a change in labor grade, not a different job. Just be sure to mention somewhere in the text that you started as an intern for full disclosure.